# App name for private B2B app distributed via the Volume Purchase Program

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, b2b, apple-vpp

I am developing a B2B app which will be distributed privately via the VPP. An iTunes connect entry has been made to reserve the name whilst development is occurring.

What will happen with the app name if it is only made available privately via the VPP?

Can another app use the name on the public app store?